# Cassandra does not log anywhere

Tags: cassandra, log4j

I start working on an old version of cassandra (1.1) that uses log4j, the problem is 'there is no logs anywhere' after some investigations i found two files from which we can change the log setting :

1/ The log4j-server.properties, settings ares supposed to plug in syslog (but it does not work)

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN,SYSLOG

log4j.logger.org.apache.thrift.server.TNonblockingServer=ERROR
log4j.appender.SYSLOG=org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.SyslogHost=localhost
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.Facility=Local0
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.FacilityPrinting=false
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.layout.ConversionPattern=%m
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.header = true
```

2/ The /etc/default/cassandra file which contains the $CASSANDRA_LOG_DIR (

```
CASSANDRA_LOG_DIR=/$USER/logs/cassandra
```

I have the same settings on all the servers (the syslog one with log4j and the default log file ) however cassandra can log only on some servers using the defaut file (/$USER/logs/cassandra/output.log)

My question is : which setting cassandra uses by default ? and can we make cassandra write logs even without log4j ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, the Cassandra output.log is located at:  `/var/log/cassandra/output.log`

The output.log captures the stdout of the Cassandra process.

If you're attempting to change the configuration for full diagnostics, you'll want to manipulate the **log4j-server.properties** file per the information at [documenation provided by DataStax](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/configuration/configLoggingLevels_r.html).

Check the "[Changing Log Levels](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/configuration/configLoggingLevels_t.html)" section from the above link.

By default, the system.log file (the log file that log4j is writing to) is located at `/var/log/cassandra/system.log`

Referencing [DataStax Documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/configuration/configSystemLog_t.html):

> By default, logging output is placed the
> /var/log/cassandra/system.log. You can change the location of the
> output by editing the log4j.appender.R.File path. Be sure that the
> directory exists and is writable by the process running Cassandra.

You can find the full documentation for changing the log rotation for the cassandra system.log file [here](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/configuration/configSystemLog_t.html).

**Please note that the above explanation is for Cassandra <= 2.0**
If you're looking for information on logging configuration for Cassandra >= 2.1, you'll want to check out [this documentation page by DataStax](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/configuration/configLoggingLevels_r.html), as 2.1+ uses [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) instead of log4j.  Thank you, phact for the note!

Comment: Also, as of 2.1, Cassandra uses logback not log4j

Comment: @phact It appears user3196353 is using Cassandra 1.1.

Comment: Right just noting for future users

Comment: Thanks, @phact.  I have updated the answer to reflect your note!

Comment: Thank you @mbeacom for your answer, i found the solution to my problem, there was a parameter (--output $LOG_FILE ) used by the JVM missing in the cassandra init script  (the script was customised by the sysadmin team). In fact, in a normal case, your reply answer perfectly to my question.

Comment: @Dady09 Glad you got it all sorted out!